# compileStatement or db.insert in android

Tags: android, sqlite, query-optimization, android-sqlite

I want to insert records into table multiple number of times, I have the choice to either use compileStatement or use db.insert as shown below.

```
String TABLENAME = "table"; //fields in table: id, name
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO "+TABLENAME+" VALUES(?,?);");  
statement.bindLong(1,666);  
statement.bindString(2,"john");
statement.executeInsert();
```

or

```
String TABLENAME = "table";
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("id", 666);
values.put("name", "john");
db.insert(TABLENAME, null, values);
```

Which one should be optimal?

EDIT:-
The application which I am running is single threaded.

Comment: Use transactions if you want better performance.

Comment: I am using this and similar code segments to insert into multiple tables, and I intend to rollback all the table if any of the insert fails, so I have enclosed them in beginTransaction and endTransaction and setTransactionSuccessful if all inserts are successful. Can you elaborate how I should change this approach

Comment: Your approach so far seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

`insert()` compiles the SQL on each invocation while the `compileStatement()` approach compiles the SQL only once. When the same SQL with different bind arguments is used more than once, the `compileStatement()` approach does less work and is faster.

In addition, consider wrapping the inserts in a transaction to reduce time spent waiting on I/O.

Comment: I am inserting in multiple tables, insertion in all the tables I have wrapped in transaction, I intend to fail all of them, in case any one of insert fails. can you elaborate how the approach should be changed for wrapping in transaction

Comment: 1. Start a transaction. 2. Begin a `try` block. 3. Do your inserts in the `try` 4. Set the transaction successful in the `try`. 5. End the transaction in the `try`'s `finally` block.

Comment: I currently use:

`db.beginTransaction();`
`try`
`{`
`  //insert in table A`
`  //insert in table B`
`  //insert in table C`
`  //insert in table D`
`  db.setTransactionSuccessful();`
`}`
`catch(Exception e)`
`{
`  //catch the exceptions`
`}`
`finally{`
`   db.endTransaction();`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

In theory, a compiled statement is better, but on an Android device, it is unlikely that you are handling so many records that the difference matters.
(If you want to be sure, you have to measure yourself.)